# Getting the newest APIs or guiding of the Rosserial Android?

Tags: android, ros

I'm really new to the ROSSERIAL ANDROID, and unfortunately there's nearly no more detailed information in [ROS.org](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_android). The official site had provided the [APIs](http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/rosserial_android/html/annotated.html) that pushed by *Adam Stambler*, however, its latest update date is nearly 4 years ago, which comes a huge mount of differences compare with his repository-resource in [github](https://github.com/adasta/rosserial_android) at 2011. The problem is when I'm follwing the [guiding](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment) and his APIs to built the demo in Android Studio, there's coming a lots of API's mistakes in classes.

So, I'm wonder is there anyone had built a successful example based on *Adam Stambler* APIs in ROS.org? And I'm wonder is there a useful guiding to following to set the configurations in Android Studio to applying the *rosserial android* too?

Any suggestions would welcome, help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the official API is too old to follow, and fortunately there's come a more better way (give up ***rosserial***, cause it's an old way) in Android to transport messages with the good support of ***[android_core](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/kinetic/android_tutorial_pubsub)*** in ***[ros_java](https://github.com/rosjava)***, so it's time that you should quit this way to make a try in **ros_java**. And fortunately there's also a good way to make it work that just transport messages in your application without a support of the ros-environment, help this can help the beginners like me to build theirs applications. Good luck! Myself's question for build your first [ros-android pubsub demo](http://answers.ros.org/question/258980/problems-to-set-buildgradle-files-in-my-demo-that-built-based-on-official-example-android_tutorial_pubsub/) maybe can help you!